# Interest Rate vs. Annual Percentage Yield (APY)

Tags: united-states, savings, interest-rate, bonds, apy

I'm curious as to what the difference between the Interest Rate and Annual Percentage Yield is.

For example:
This Bank I was looking at offers 0.45% interest rate on savings account balances over $100,000. It also has an APY of 0.45% on balances >$100,000.

I'm not interested in opening a savings account with $100,000+ for 0.45% so I'm not looking for feedback on whether that's a good idea or not, I'm just curious as to when they numbers are different, and why. I know they can be different with government bonds, but I would like a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: Your APY is earnings from interest normalized over one year.

Interest can be simple or compounding at different rates (daily, monthly, quarterly). An APY is an attempt to provide a normalized yield value that can more easily be compared across different interest products.

As a bonus, APR is the annualized *rate* of compounding, but does not take into account the actual effect of compounding. Be sure you are comparing apples to apples, especially with loans. APR will be a lower number than APY.

Read more here

http://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/04/102904.asp